# I can't find the piecewise linear function given the following set of dependent and independent variables.

Tags: calculus

So, let's say we're in a parking lot and it costs 5 cents per minute to park at the airport with the rate dropping to 3 cents per minute after 9:00 p.m. Assume that t is the number of minutes after 8 p.m.

Find and graph the cost function c(t) for values of t satisfying $0 <= t <= 120 $

***What I think the answer is :***

So for the first part of this piecewise function is to take 0.05t for $0 <= t <= 60
It is now 9:00 p.m.

For the second part of this piecewise function is where I fall short.

The typical procedure of finding the function involving two points is to take the slope of the two points. $\frac{dependent_2 - dependent_1}{independent_2 - independent_1}$

Our dependent variable is 0.03 and 0. Our independent variables are 120 and 60.

So m should logically be $\frac{0.03}{60} = 0.0005$

So our function should be d - 0.03 = 0.0005(t - 120)

Problem is the ending fucntion in the back of my book says $p(t) = 0.03t + 1.2$.

I'm not sure how it came to this and I'm coming to you, my friends at math stackexchange for help.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your answer (for the hour between 8 and 9) is correct.

For the time after 9, don't try to use the
typical procedure for the line through two points. Think directly about the slope. It will be
$$
0.03 \frac{\text{\$}}{\text{minute past } 9}
$$
so the formula for the time after 9 will be the full cost for the first hour plus the cost for the added time. That is
$$
3.00 + 0.03(t-60).
$$

That simplifies algebraically to the answer in the book.

Comment: Ethan, the problem with this answer is that I don't know the algorithm used to GET this and cannot replicate the results. It's like. . . You want me to think directly about the slope, and not use the typical procedure for the line through two points. Okay, but now that I'm thinking directly about the slope, what do I do? Like how did you GET this conclusion? Do I just decide that "oh this problem can't be solved by the normal formula, so let me cook this new thing up." ???

Comment: You don't solve problems with formulas or algorithms, you solve them by thinking. Sometimes your thoughts will lead you to use a particular formula or algorithm. Here's how I thought about your problem. I recognized the $0,05$ and $0.03$ as  _rates_  (which I always write rates with their proper units) and I know from experience that rates in a word problem are slopes in a graph.

Comment: Be that as it may, your answer still is unsatisfactory and I did a lot of thinking and practice and figured it out. If you're interested in the conclusion I came to, it is on my profile in the form of a new question.