# finding the piecewise linear function in a way that the results can be replicated or I can carry it forward to other problems

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

We have a parking deck that it costs 5cents per minute to park at. After 9:00 p.m it costs $3$ cents per minute to park on the deck.
We assume in this problem that parking starts at $8:00$ p.m.
The objective is to find the piecewise function and graph the equation.
So, the first thing I do is identify my points. with $(0,0) (60,3)$

With that my slope is $m = \frac{3-0}{60-0}$ therefore, $m = 0.05$

I take the point slope equation of y - y$_1$ = m(x - x$_1$)
Which is $y - 0 =0.05(x-0) $

So my first equation is $0.05x$

Next, I need to find out what happens when the time hits 9:00 p.m. More specifically, we go from

$0 \leq x \leq 60$

to

$60 \lt x \leq 120$

So when I look at this equation, right? I notice that 60 is not included, 60 is a time variable for use of the function when it has 5 cents per minute.

**What I think I can do :**

So, my first thought is to take the points and involve them in the slope, but not in the plotting of points in the equation.  So, I have the points $(60, 3),(120,3.6)$ However, my leftmost point is not included. So, rather than use (60, 3) for the slope equation, I can use (60,1.8) as this is where the function begins, and this is how it scales.

Specifically,  I create a slope $m = \frac{3.6-1.8}{120-60}$

so that  m = 0.03.

Next, I use the plot point line formula so that y - y$_2$= m(x-x$_2$)
But here, my $x_1$ and $y_1$ are different, since the slope itself  is 0.03,and uses the non-inclusive point of (60,1.8) to define its growth. But, it is between the points of (60, 3) and (120, 3.6)

So,

$y - 3 = 0.03(x - 60)$

$y - 3 = 0.03x - 1.8$

Then I add three to both sides

$y = 0.03x + 1.2$

Which is congruent with the answer key in the back of the book. Did I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the direct question

> Did I do this correctly?

is simply "yes", if what matters is the correct answer.

But it's rather longwinded. In each part of the problem you first found a second point on the graph using the given slope and then used that second point to calculate the slope you already knew.

Here is the first version of you question:
[I can't find the piecewise linear function given the following set of dependent and independent variables.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4035955/i-cant-find-the-piecewise-linear-function-given-the-following-set-of-dependent/4036098?noredirect=1#comment8339584_4036098)